# Basic solution for IP address failover on Windows

Tags: windows-server-2003, failover, fault-tolerance

I'm trying to find a basic solution that will allow an IP address to fail over from one Win2k3 server to a standby one. I've got my own programs that can detect when a failure has occurred and trigger the IP address failover but I'm struggling to find a good mechanism or product to handle the failover.

I've spent some time testing out the inbuilt Windows Cluster Service but after half a day I don't think it's the answer. My service runs in a hosted environment and the overhead of setting up a domain controller, quorum disk resource and whatever else it needs after I get past those two is looking like a lot of overkill just to move an IP address from one server to another.

Likewise with [Zeus Traffic Manager](http://www.zeus.com/products/traffic-manager) it seems like a good product but again it has a lot of bells and whistles I don't need and therefore don't want to pay the high price for.

Should I be looking at coming up with a custom script that simply brings up the IP address on the secondary server when a failure occurs?